# Javascript edit external file

Tags: file, external, edit

Okay so I'm trying to make a script that can edit an external .txt file. I want to be able to do something like /name John Doe and it saves that name in the file that the command is supposed to edit.

Another example would be I have a file called List.txt associated with the command /todo, whenever I do /todo *** it adds whatever came after the command to the List.txt file.

Is there any way I can do this in javascript?

Comment: Please try to rephrase your question, its not very clear.

Comment: Thank you for actually telling me that I didn't make it clear enough instead of just downvoting it. Will do right now!

Comment: What language are you using? Are you using batch files?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using javascript. Made that edit in the question also just now.

Comment: Are you trying to read/write these files on a server, or a clients machine?

Comment: I'm trying to make it edit a file I have on my machine itself.

Comment: @NinjaMagii is "my machine" functioning as the server, client, or neither?

Comment: It's functioning as the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in luck, it appears that [HTML5 actually supports this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/). Of course you'll have to run it through a browser, I don't know if you can hack it somehow to [work from bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791758/how-can-i-execute-javascript-in-bash).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible to do this by creating an ajax http request to an server server side script that edits the file based on the http request's content.

Heres an example PHP serverside script the handle the ajax request:

**Note**: This example has a lot of **security issues** and is **untested**

```
<?php
    $command = $_POST['command'];
    $argument = $_POST['argument'];
    if ($command == "name") {
        $file = fopen("names.txt", "a");
        fwrite($file, $argument."\n");
        fclose($file);
    } else if ($command == "todo") {
        $file = fopen("todo.txt", "a");
        fwrite($file, $argument."\n");
        fclose($file);
    }
?>
```

There is also a great tutorial on AJAX requests [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)

They also have a php tutorial on [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp)

ps. sorry it took so long.